# IOS-table view not reusing table view cell properly

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development.
I am mapping JSON data in a table view, which is exactly the same size as screen. But the first cell of the table view shows wrong data and also data loads in cells when cells completely enters the viewport. I have searched enough about this.. Don't know what is the right solution for this.

Comment: add some code if you need help on this

Comment: Show use what your 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method looks like.

Comment: What you done, pls share your code

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself. I was missing `forIndexPath:indexPath` in 
`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"feedCell" **forIndexPath:indexPath**];`